# Is there anyway to update @Bean at runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

For my project I want to download from an API and store this information in a map. Furthermore I want to have the map as a bean in another class. I suspect the API to update regularly so I have set a @Schedule for downloading the XML file from the API.
To the problem... How can I update the map with the information from the API every time the XML is downloaded. I do not want to reboot the application each time.

I am very new to the Spring framework so if there is a more elegant method to do this please let me know.

```
data class DataContainer(val dictionary: MutableMap<String, String>)

@Configuration
@Component
class DownloadRenhold {
    var dict: MutableMap<String, String> = xmlToDict("/renhold.xml")
    val dataContainer: DataContainer
        @Bean
        get() = DataContainer(dict)

    fun download(link: String, path: String) {
        URL(link).openStream().use { input ->
            FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->
                input.copyTo(output)
            }
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    fun scheduledDL() {
        download("www.link.com","src/main/resources/renhold.xml")
            dict = xmlToDict("/renhold.xml")
}
```

````
class Controller {

    @GetMapping(value = ["/{orgnummer}"]) // @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    fun orgNrRequest(@PathVariable("orgnummer") nr: String): String? {
        var actx = AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DownloadRenhold::class.java)
        var dataContainer = actx.getBean(DataContainer::class.java)
        return dataContainer.dictionary[nr]
    }
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to not have `DataContainer` as a bean directly. Instead inject `DownRenhold` into `Controller` as a singleton bean. Something along these lines:

```
// No need to make this class a Configuration. Plain Component would suffice.
// @Configuration
@Component
class DownloadRenhold {
    var _dataContainer: DataContainer = null
    var dataContainer: DataContainer
        get() = _dataContainer

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    fun scheduledDL() {
        _dataContainer = // do your download thing and create a DataContainer instance.
    }
}

class Controller {
    @Autowired
    var dataProvider: DownloadRenhold

    @GetMapping(value = ["/{orgnummer}"])
    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    fun orgNrRequest(@PathVariable("orgnummer") nr: String): String? {
        dataProvider.dataContainer // access the current data container
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this made the application work!!